# Are 'complete' and 'completed' interchangeable in the sentence?

Tags: usage

I referred to several dictionaries, but I am not sure both can be used in the sentence.

> *Without coffee, my happiness couldn’t be **complete**!*

vs.

> *Without coffee, my happiness couldn't be **completed**!*

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't interchangeable.

In the first sentence **complete** is an adjective. It means (in this context) *entire/utter/total*. "My happiness was complete" means "I was utterly/totally/completely happy."

The second sentence uses the **past participle** of the verb 'complete' as an adjective: **completed**. It means 'finished.' We describe a task or undertaking as 'completed' when we finish it. Runners complete marathons. I sometimes complete a crossword. "My happiness was completed" means it was **finished**!

Your first sentence is the idiomatic one.